# When #if SERVICE does work and when it does not?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I often used to use (and as far as I can remember it was working just fine)

```
        public static void Main() {
#if SERVICE
            ServiceBase.Run(new MyService());
#else
            ....
#endif
```

in services code so I can run it as console or register with `installutil` and run as service.

But... since some updates or with switch to 4.5.1 ( or even maybe in release build ) it just doesn't work anymore. Whenever I use `installutil` or just run as console it's using code for console, e.g. not for `SERVICE` and it fails because I used `Console.ReadKey` there and sure service can't deal with it.

Maybe I am doing something wrong and there is alternative ways of doing it?

Comment: Are you sure the SERVICE is supplied automatically? Wasn't it something in your project-config that got lost?

Comment: It's not, so far as I'm aware, even been a built in part of the project system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... so I can run it as console or register with installutil and run as service

That can't have been enough.  The `#if SERVICE` is a compile  time condititon, it cannot produce different behaviours depending on how you run it. It needs a different Build configuration.

My guess is that you lost a piece of tooling or forgot a certain habit after that upgrade.

Comment: I see... possibly, I can't now find / google another information about such usage.